# how to keep default end time 3hrs from starttime?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dom

First check facebook event create page the link is http://www.facebook.com/?ref=home#!/events/create.php I am using the start and end date time of that page in my application.My question is if i set **start time 12pm** ,**the default end time** should be 3hrs after that that is **end time =3pm** (if the user does not set end time)

code for start time

```
<select name="menu" class="style24">
  <option value="00:00" <?php if($todaytime=="01"){echo "selected";}?>>12:00am</option>
  <option value="00:30" <?php if($todaytime=="01"){echo "selected";}?>>12:30am</option>
  <option value="01:00" <?php if($todaytime=="02"){echo "selected";}?>>1:00am</option>
  <option value="01:30" <?php if($todaytime=="02"){echo "selected";}?>>1:30am</option>
  <option value="02:00" <?php if($todaytime=="03"){echo "selected";}?>>2:00am</option>
  <option value="02:30" <?php if($todaytime=="03"){echo "selected";}?>>2:30am</option>
  <option value="03:00" <?php if($todaytime=="04"){echo "selected";}?>>3:00am</option>
  <option value="03:30" <?php if($todaytime=="04"){echo "selected";}?>>3:30am</option>
</select>
```

code for end time

```
<select name="menu1" class="style24">
  <option value="00:00" <?php if($todaytime=="01"){echo "selected";}?>>12:00am</option>
  <option value="00:30" <?php if($todaytime=="01"){echo "selected";}?>>12:30am</option>
  <option value="01:00" <?php if($todaytime=="02"){echo "selected";}?>>1:00am</option>
  <option value="01:30" <?php if($todaytime=="02"){echo "selected";}?>>1:30am</option>
  <option value="02:00" <?php if($todaytime=="03"){echo "selected";}?>>2:00am</option>
  <option value="02:30" <?php if($todaytime=="03"){echo "selected";}?>>2:30am</option>
  <option value="03:00" <?php if($todaytime=="04"){echo "selected";}?>>3:00am</option>
  <option value="03:30" <?php if($todaytime=="04"){echo "selected";}?>>3:30am</option>
  <option value="04:00" <?php if($todaytime=="05"){echo "selected";}?>>4:00 am</option>
</select>
```

`$todaytime` is defined as `date("H", time())`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: You should really use a for loop. Moreover, your code does not correctly distinguish the half hours.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your first select has id="start" and the other selct has id="end", the code should be like this (pure javascript and jquery):

```
  <script>   
    function hhmm2minutes(hhmm){
       var hhmmArray = hhmm.split(":");
       return parseInt(hhmmArray[0], 10)*60 + parseInt(hhmmArray[1], 10);
    }
    function minutes2hhmm(minutes){
       minutes = minutes % (24*60); //To avoid having hour > 23
       function addZero(x){
          return (x < 10 ? "0"+x : ""+x) ;
       }
       var mm = minutes % 60;
       var hh = (minutes - mm)/60;
       return addZero(hh) + ":" + addZero(mm);   
    }

    function setEnd3HoursFromStart(){
       var hhmmStart = $("#start").val();
       if(hhmmStart=="") return;
       var hhmmEnd = minutes2hhmm(hhmm2minutes(hhmmStart) + 180); //Add 180 minutes
       $("#end").val(hhmmEnd);
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
      setEnd3HoursFromStart();
      $("#start").change(function(){
         setEnd3HoursFromStart();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Hope this helped. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Make your

```
<?php   if($todaytime=="01"){echo "selected";} ?>
```

into a function call:

```
<?php selectstarttime(time) ?>  //in your starttime code
<?php selectendtime(time) ?>  // in your endtime code

function selectstarttime(time){
 if (something like time==currentTime){
  return "selected";
 }
 else
  return "";
 } 
}

function selectendtime(time){
 if (something like time==currentTime + 3hours){
  return "selected";
 }
 else
  return "";
 } 
}
```